# Crystal report unlinked Subreport

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, report

I have a crystal report with several parts

- Page Header a (Company Information)
- Page Header b (Sub-Report: has list of specific countries)
- Page Header c (Sub-Report: has list of specific Products)
- Page Header d (Sub-Report: has list of specific items)

The data source of the report is given by a Dataset "DS1" through C# Application (Push Method)

Because of the complex logic in the background, it is decided to have Dataset "DS1" with 4 Data tables (tbl0,tbl1,tbl2,tbl3) to hold ***separately*** the correct data in the Dataset.

The dataset doesn't have any relationships, because I have loaded directly the final data result in the relative Data Tables in the Dataset

```
DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
DataTable dt3 = new DataTable();
DataTable dt4 = new DataTable();

Load_CompanyInfo(country_ID, ref dt1);
Load_Countries(_ApprovalID, ref dt2);
Load_Products(_ApprovalID, ref dt3);
Load_Items(_ApprovalID, ref dt4);

_ds_tmp.Tables.Add(dt1);
_ds_tmp.Tables.Add(dt2);
_ds_tmp.Tables.Add(dt3);
_ds_tmp.Tables.Add(dt4);
```

In the Form ReportView.cs, I have assigned the Dataset to the report.

```
rep_c_single.SetDataSource(ds.Tables[0]);                   // Main company info
rep_c_single.Subreports[0].SetDataSource(ds.Tables[1]);     // countries
rep_c_single.Subreports[1].SetDataSource(ds.Tables[2]);     // products
rep_c_single.Subreports[2].SetDataSource(ds.Tables[3]);     // items
rep_c_single.Refresh();
cr_Viewer.ReportSource = rep_c_single;
```

on the report file, the sub reports doesn't have link field to the main report.
Because final Data is prepared in the Data Tables. 
I just want to display the Data in the Sub report independent from the Main Report data source.

What I have till now, the sub reports lists all countries and all products, not what in the data table exists.

***EDIT:***
**It is important to mention: the sub reports and main reports don't have any relations. I want only to PUSH data to the relative Sub-reports**

thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

i'm not entirely sure.. but i've done this once..

> > 1. make sure your report has a group based on the primary key of the main report     (with which you want to link all the sub reports)
> > 2. right click on the sub report
> > 3. change sub report links
> > 4. in the available fields select the column name of the sub report or respective data table
> > 5. click on add to add it into the fields to link
> >        it'll also show in the sub-report paramater to use drop down list underneath
> > 6. check the flag -- select data in sub-report based on field
> > 7. select the main report primary key group you made in the first step

Hope it works.. :)

Comment: Thanks for rely,, but the main report data don't have connection to the sub report.

Comment: it must have some common field on the basis of which you with to connect the two..?